# check box checked false only selected check box

Tags: jquery, checkbox

i have some dynamically checkbox i have only checkbox checked maximum 3.However, if the fourth checkbox is checked, it should be skipped. and also have unchecked the fourth check box. my problem is all check box is unchecked.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $(":checkbox").change(function() {
     if(this.checked) {
    var numberOfChecked = $('input:checkbox:checked').length;
     if(numberOfChecked > 3 ){
       alert("Maxium Allowed 3 in Slider") ;
       $(":checkbox").prop("checked", false);
 return ;
    }
   }

        });
    });
```

i need only 3 check box checking

```
  I have a bike: <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"><br>
  I have a car: <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"><br>

   I have a bus: <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"><br>

     I have a mobile: <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"><br>
  I have an airplane: <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Airplane">
```

Comment: $(this).prop("checked", false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this` keyword for grabbing the current checkbox clicked.

What you did is unchecking all checkboxes as per selector $(":checkbox")

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(":checkbox").change(function() {
     if (this.checked) {
        var numberOfChecked = $('input:checkbox:checked').length;
        if (numberOfChecked > 3 ) {
            alert("Maximum Allowed 3 in Slider") ;
            //COMMENT: below line fixes your problem
            $(this).prop("checked", false);
            return ;
        }
      }
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
I have a bike: <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"><br>
I have a car: <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"><br>
I have a bus: <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"><br>
I have a mobile: <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"><br>
I have an airplane: <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Airplane">
```